# Definition of total probaility

Tags: probability

An example:- To talk about "the law of sines", we need to know what sines are. That is, the term "sine (of  an angle)" must be clearly defined first before we can go on to study the law.

My quesition is about "the law of total probability". I have googled through several sites and they all go directly to describe how to apply that law and I can hardly find a definition about "total probability".

Maybe my search is NOT deep enough. Any links? Thanx.

Comment: I don't think there is a thing called "total probability".  The so-called Law of Total Probability just says that $P(A)=\sum_i P(A\cap B_i)$ where the $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint and exhaustive, at least up to probability $0$.  Or were you after something else?

Comment: For example, "the law of large number". We never want to define what a large number is, but this law still makes sense.

Comment: That's just the name of the theorem.  You don't have to understand the name to understand the theorem.  Many names of theorems, functions, and whatnot are inappropriate somehow or other, and it doesn't make a bit of difference.

Comment: "[One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296)" -- Richard Feynman

Comment: The "total probability" just means that the sum of the probability of the $A\cap B_i$ amounts exactly to the "whole" probability, the total of the probability, which is 1.

Comment: I say, what is the total amount of money in your wallet? You pull out bills, adding the numbers on their faces, and tell me a number. I say, "You showed me how to total the money in your wallet, but I want to know: What is the total amount of money in a wallet, in general? So you give me a procedure: "Pull out each bill, note its face value, enter it in a calculator app, press "+", ...." I say, yes, everyone tells me that is how to calculate the total amount of money in a wallet, but I want a definition: What is the concept of total amount of money in a wallet, apart from all the money in it?